# When PWA feature will be available in Magento 2 out of the box?

Tags: magento2, pwa

does anyone know if Magento planning to add PWA (Progressive Web Apps) feature out of the box in the next releases e.g. in v2.3.0 or v2.4.0 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As per the announcement in Magento imagine conference 2018, **`Progressive Web Apps`** (PWA) will be in the main features of `Magento 2.3`.

**Magento 2.3, has been announced and scheduled for Q3 of 2018**.

You can check unofficial [**Magento2 Roadmap**](https://github.com/avoelkl/mage2roadmap) that mentioned all the features from multiple sources.

Some Other useful links that help to understand more about M2.3 features:

https://trellis.co/blog/expect-magento-2018/

https://www.ctidigital.com/blog/magento-2.3

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-3-open-source-commerce-features.html

https://twitter.com/JohnHughes1984/status/988882093865250818

Answer (score 0):

It's already out to use in Magento230. Official magento doc see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.0OpenSource.html?_ga=2.20656574.769510250.1543917509-1921157898.1531735057]